# Rails: How to remove n+1 query when we need to query association inside loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have output as result in code having queries in it (only showing basic one here)
So basically I need sum of the custom line items as well as all line items

```
results = Order.includes(:customer, :line_items).where('completed_at IS NOT NULL')

results.each do |result|
  custom_items_sum = result.line_items.where(line_item_type: 'custom').sum(:amount)
   total_sum = result.line_items.sum(:amount)
end
```

In this code, there is n+1 query issue, I have tried adding includes but for sure it is not going to work as we have another query inside the loop, Any help will be appreciated??

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to trigger other queries in the loop you need to avoid methods which work on relations and use that ones which work on collections. Try

```
custom_items_sum = result.line_items.
    select { |line_item| line_item.line_item_type == 'custom' }.
    sum(&:amount)
```

This should work without n+1 queries.

Note that it's possible to write just one query and avoid this computation anyway but that's beyond the scope of your question :)

Comment: @Urus actually this was a very little part of the implementation, I am using ajax-datatables-rails with multiple queries over there. At this point, this solution is preferable because of other complexities. Otherwise implementing raw query is best solution.   Also it should be `.sum(&:amount)` not `.sum(:amount)`

Comment: Obviously a single query is a best solution here. well, not raw though, it's perfectly possible write a single one with active record as well

Answer (score 2):

Rails was never known to be robust enough as ORM. Use plain SQL instead:

```
results =
  Order.connection.execute <<-SQL
    SELECT order.id, SUM(line_items.amount)
    FROM orders
      JOIN line_items
      ON (line_items.order_id = orders.id)
    WHERE orders.completed_at IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY orders.id
    HAVING line_items.line_item_type = 'custom'
  SQL
```

That way you’ll get all the intermediate sums in a single query, which is way faster than performing all the calculations in ruby.

Comment: In this how I will get a sum of all line items as well? this query will give me   order and its custom line items sum?

Comment: Total sum is a single call, just do it in Rails, or write another query.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin just because rails doesn't hand you the silver spoon for this type of thing (like they do for most) does not mean that it cannot be done without raw sql. `Arel` is an extremely powerful and efficient SQL generator and allows the full flexibility of a truly method based implementation. It also integrates directly into AR based queries https://stackoverflow.com/a/55953805/1978251

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the scoping block. The following code generates very clean SQL queries.

```
Order.includes(:line_items).where.not(completed_at: nil).scoping do
   @custom_items_sum = Order.where(line_items: { line_item_type: 'custom' })
                            .sum(:amount)
   @total_sum        = Order.sum(:amount)
end
```

There's not that much documentation about the `scoping` block but it scopes your model to the ActiveRecord requests made before (here : `where('completed IS NOT NULL')` and with the `:line_items` included).

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just because [@AlekseiMatiushkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2035262/aleksei-matiushkin) says write it in raw SQL let's do the same with rails

```
order_table = Order.arel_table
line_items_table = LineItem.arel_table
custom_items = Arel::Table.new(:custom_items)
Order.select(
   order_table[Arel.star],
   line_items_table[:amount].sum.as('total_sum'),
   custom_items[:amount].sum.as('custom_items_sum')
).joins(
   order_table.join(line_items_table).on(
     line_items_table[:order_id].eq(order_table[:id])
   ).join(
      Arel::Nodes::As.new(line_items_table,:custom_items), 
      Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin
   ).on( 
      custom_items[:order_id].eq(order_table[:id]).and(
       custom_items[:line_item_type].eq('custom')
      ) 
   ).join_sources
).where(
   order_table[:completed_at].not_eq(nil)
).group(:id)
```

This will produce an `ActiveRecord::Relation` of `Order` objects with a virtual attributes of `total_sum` and `custom_items_sum` using the following query

```
SELECT 
  orders.*,
  SUM(line_items.amount) AS total_sum,
  SUM(custom_items.amount) As custom_items_sum
FROM 
  orders
  INNER JOIN line_items ON line_items.order_id = orders.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN line_items AS custom_items ON custom_items.order_id = orders.id
    AND custom_items.line_item_type = 'custom'
WHERE 
  orders.completed_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
  orders.id
```

This should handle the request in a single query by using 2 joins to aggregate the needed data.